# How to setup local repository for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: repository

I am new with Ubuntu.

I want to setup a local repository for Ubuntu 12.04, because i don't have internet access on my laptop. I downloaded repository using wget on windows machine and its download directory structure under us.archive.ubuntu.com directory.

Please let me how i setup local repository using it.

Thanks for response (in Advance).

Comment: Please clarify:  Do don't **want** to connect this laptop to access the "Inter Web", but you can access same from **Windows**. Or, you really ***can't access the Internet*** !?

Answer (score 2):

You can now add the repository path (us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) to /etc/apt/sources.list file

For example:-

Suppose you have downloaded it to /media/Data/us.archive.ubuntu.com/
First backup your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
```

Open /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb file:///media/Data/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe multiverse
```

Comment: performing the apt-get update was the key.