# Installing packages into local directory?

Tags: apt, compiling

I'd like to install software packages, similar to `apt-get install <foo>` but:

1. Without `sudo`, and
2. Into a local directory

The purpose of this exercise is to isolate independent builds in my [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server.

I don't mind compiling from source, if that's what it takes, but obviously I'd prefer the simplest approach possible. I tried `apt-get source --compile <foo>` as mentioned [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-sourcehandling.en.html) but I can't get it working for packages like autoconf. I get the following error:

`dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: help2man`

I've got help2man compiled in a local directory, but I don't know how to inform apt-get of that. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I found an answer that *almost* works at https://askubuntu.com/a/350/23678. The problem with `chroot` is that it requires sudo. The problem with `apt-get source` is that I don't know how to resolve dependencies. I must say, `chroot` looks **very** appealing. Is there an equivalent command that doesn't require sudo?

Comment: I suggest that's a duplicate of this question :

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/147654/how-to-setup-local-repository-for-ubuntu-12-04][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147654/how-to-setup-local-repository-for-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: @kamil, it's not. I'm not trying to install without network access. I'm trying to install without `sudo` and into a non-system directory.

Comment: If you don't have root on the system, you will not be able to resolve dependencies *easily*. It is sometimes possible, though; you would have to start installing the software in your home, starting with the bottom-most dependencies, and modifying your LD_PATH so that programs can find their libraries. However, you will fail if any of the packages requires root (or suid) to run.

Comment: @January, I'm trying to compile a software project inside an automated build system. As far as I know, none of its dependencies (required to compile) require root.

Comment: Well, then install the dependencies one by one manually. I don't see another solution that does not require root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Comment: @user68186 Yes, https://askubuntu.com/a/350/23678 is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is, in general, not doable, because you would mess with the apt dependencies system.

There are two solutions:

1. Install the source package, change into the source directory, configure and install the package irrespective of the packaging systems manually to a directory of your choice.

   ```
   apt-get source <package>
   ```

   This does not need root, downloads the package source, unpacks it in a directory within the current directory. You can then change to that directory, make modifications to the source, configure the installation to another target etc.

   Configuring to which installation directory the programs should go depends, however, on the particular program. Many programs use the `./configure --prefix localdir` to target the installation to localdir; but this is by far not always the case.
2. Create a chroot environment into which you will install the packages:

   ```
   debootstrap precise myfancyinstall
   ```

   Now you have created a dummy installation in the myfancyinstall/ directory

   ```
   chroot myfancyinstall
   ```

   You can use apt-get install within the chroot cage to install whatever you wish.

Comment: This looks promising. Using `apt-get source` without `--compile` seems to suppress the warning about unmet dependencies (allowing me to resolve them myself)

Comment: Is there a way to get packages that have no source this way as well?

Comment: Solution (2) will work regardless. Otherwise, you are on your own: maybe there is another way of installing package. Or download the deb package file and unpack it with ar: `ar vx mypackage.deb`. Then analyse the contents of the package and find out how to install it manually.

Answer (score 17):

using a bash shell, and acquiring the "package.deb" file (assuming pack name is "package")
you can run the following command to accomplish what you want - installing the package so that your home directory is treated the same way "/" would be treated in a normal install.

This is the command:

```
apt-get download package; dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME package.deb
```

You might face some errors, such as $HOME/var/lib/dpkg/lock is missing
so just create all the missing files you will get from the errors and then the install should work without sudo.

notice that if "apt-get download" doesn't work, you can try "apt download" or "apitutde download package".

if neither methods work, you can just download the package manually from http://packages.ubuntu.com/

another method would be to run the chroot command with the parameter $HOME and then installing the same way as above only without --root=$HOME.
that command would bring you in a shell where "/" is your current $HOME.
to return to normal mode don't forget to "exit"

good luck.

Comment: After creating the missing files dpkg complained about, it just started segfaulting.

Comment: Please note that `man dpkg` mentions that when using the --force family of options the following applies: "Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts only. Using  them without fully understanding their effects may break your whole system."

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a shared web-hoster with `ssh` access but no `apt-get` no root etc. or a similarly restricted system the following may work for you.
It worked for me on a system where `uname -a` returned something like `SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2~bpo8+1 (2017-01-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
# examples tried on a shared hoster with ssh access but no apt-get no root etc.
# http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.1.3+dfsg-0.1_amd64.deb
# https://github.com/dvorka/hstr/releases/download/1.25/hstr_1.25-1_amd64.deb

debURL="http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_4.1.3+dfsg-0.1_amd64.deb"
# get the filename only, remove all till last slash "/"
# see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal
debFile=${debURL##*/}
# change to your desired directory for installation/unpacking; here: $HOME
cd $HOME
# get the .deb file (no dependencies checked or resolved here)
curl -OL $debURL 
# unpack only the data part from the .deb file
# see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29
ar p $debFile data.tar.xz | tar xJv --strip-components=2 -f - 
rm -v $debFile # clean up
echo "Done unpacking $debFile into $(pwd)"
```

Comment: You're a genius man :) Thanks!!!

Comment: This is far better than the above two and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

unpacking the .deb file might or might not work for your application. My suggestion is to get source code and compile, and install it in your local folder. That should be the universal solution for this question.