# Custom installation paths for software

Tags: software-installation

I'm super new to ubuntu. I'd love if someone could explain to me why (when instaling two software: **vs code and anaconda navigator**), in the installation process it's advised not to change the path of installation ([How to choose install location using "apt-get install"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404824/how-to-choose-install-location-using-apt-get-install)). Nevertheless, I also found this, while searching that says that we should not install software on user/local ([Where to install programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6897/where-to-install-programs)). So... Should or should I not change the path, when it's advised to be installed on home/user?

Comment: [Your first link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404824/how-to-choose-install-location-using-apt-get-install) is clear that you cannot choose the path of .deb packages. We can give you better advice if you link to whatever instructions you are following -- there are MANY ways to install software.

Comment: Generally speaking if you are new to Linux then leaving things in their defaults helps in several ways.  The normal package manager knows where they are.  They get automatically added to its index. All the linked libraries will work and work after updates. In the early days of computers all programs were standalone like buying a car. Now when you buy software you buy only the outside. The engine and wheels come from other places and are shared with other programs. Changing locations can mess this relationship up.

Comment: @Bilesh Ganguly Thanks for improving my question =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda causes more problems with paths than any other common Ubuntu application I can think of. If you install Anaconda in a custom location, you'll end up uninstalling it when you find out how much work it takes is to maintain it.

You can do whatever you want to with Visual Studio Code, but I recommend installing the Visual Studio Code snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu because you can install it directly from the Ubuntu Software app. If you install the Visual Studio Code snap package it will install it to the snap package's default location (snap packages are not installed at `/usr/local/`) and that can't be easily changed.

Comment: hey @karel thank you very much for ur knowledgeable explanation :) could u please enligt me on the "Avoid placing your local binaries directly under /usr, because according to the FHS, that hierarchy is reserved for the software provided by the Linux distribution (in this case, Ubuntu)." provided in mine second link?

Really appreciate it :)

Comment: The FHS s the ultimate authority on this topic. It recommends to avoid placing your local binaries directly under `/usr`, because according to the FHS, that hierarchy is reserved for the software provided by the Linux distribution. This reduces the possibility of path errors (for example path errors of Anaconda users as I mentioned) which can be difficult to troubleshoot and time-consuming to repair.

Comment: So to conclude, all instalations done by the providers of the software, that are done in home/users are done correctly, by someone who understands and most certanly with all folders in the correct places.

as a newbie and don't understanding unix terminology and the development done behind every project, is highly probably that by changing even a tiny bit, it will end up in tones of work!

many thanks :)