# apt install -- changing root directory

Tags: apt

I have a package that I need to install in /usr/local rather than /usr.  Is there an equivalent of `dpkg -root /usr/local` for `apt install`.

I am attempting to get rsyslog and syslog-ng to coexist...

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/404824/how-to-choose-install-location-using-apt-get-install

Comment: Download the package source (or go to the developers" web site), set up a build environment (start with `sudo apt install build-essential`), reconfigure the package (`./configure`), build, install. Trying to subvert a packaged product defeats one of the benefits of software packaging.

Comment: Why do you need to get them to co-exist?

Comment: For the curious:  i went back to building a package from source that installed into /usr/local.  I much prefer to use standard packages if i can.  I have rsyslog as the corporate std and the configuration is locked by puppet.  I need a syslog server for handling data for a siem and that does lots of parsing and syslog-ng is better for that. Alternative would be to run two instances of rsyslog.

Answer (score 0):

More research on this one implies it is not possible and in fact the `--root` flag on `dpkg` is also problematic as most standard `.debs` are build with a root of `\` and within that `dpkg`looks for `var/lib/dpkg` which isn't there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1200269)

Comment: I disagree, It does provide an answer i.e. "it is not possible".  I have edited the answer to remove commentary