# How do you install and run apps from a flash drive/ sd card

Tags: external-hdd

i have ubuntu on my chromebook, thus to save space, i would like to run apps from external storage. how do i do that.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory

Answer (score 0):

You can add the path of the installed applications to `.bashrc` (presuming you are using `BASH`).
Simply open the `.bashrc` with your favourite editor and insert a new line with
`PATH=$PATH:/mountpoint/bin`
where `mountpoint` is the mount point of your external storage.
`bin` is the directory of you used applications. You can even add more if you like, as for example `PATH=$PATH:/mountpoint/bin:/mountpoint/sbin:/mountpoint/usr/bin:/mountpoint/usr/sbin`.