# How to give permission to non-sudo users to download software in their own directory?

Tags: permissions, software-center, root, users, downloads

I am a sudo user to a remote node (ubuntu 20.04). My role is to facilitate multiple users of the node by generating their credentials. I downloaded RDP and remote desktop for them.

However, **none of them is able to download any software or package whatsoever** (E.g., IntelliJ). neither from the Software Centre nor through the command line.
They require the root password for the same; which I cannot give to them.
Also, downloading software as a sudo every time someone needs a new software is not feasible.

What to do?

Comment: Downloading software do not need root permissions in ubuntu 20.04. You tried it?

Comment: Yes. Intellij asks for the password.
'Authentication Required' 
'Authentication is required to install, update, or remove packages.'

Comment: This is not how Ubuntu works. You should install the software (say intelliJ) once and all the users will have access to it. Ubuntu won't allow 10 users to install the same software 10 times in 10 different places. When you use the software repositories or a deb file, Ubuntu will only install a software in a very specific way at a specific location. That's why authentication is required.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for the clean explanation. Is it the same for every repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing packages into local directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193695/installing-packages-into-local-directory)

Comment: Also see [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Comment: I tried that --force-not-root thing, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Also, giving certain leverages to users by adding permission to use apt-get without password increases vulnerability.

Comment: "Is it the same for every repository?" Yes. There are some types of binaries and software packages that can be installed by any user in their respective "home" folder (or its sub-folder). First, statically compiled binary that does not have any dependencies, can be in any folder. Second, software distributed in the AppImage package format can also be in any folder. these two types of software does not need any "installation". Any user can download/copy the executable file and set it's executable flag and run it. Needless to say running random executable file is a bad idea.